# SQL join statement between table and selection in Knex

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have SQL statement :

```
   select from resources 
          left join ( select resource_id, sum(price) as PostScoreSum from 
                      prices where '2019-06-8' < dateto and '2019-06-15' > 
                      datefrom group by resource_id ) BB on 
                     resources.resources_id = BB.resource_id")
```

Using Knex, I can write this statement as knex.raw('.....'), but after this knex statement I cannot used modify (to have chain of statements, knex.raw('...').modify...is not posible). Is it possible to write this join in Knex, between table and selection without using raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what actually your issue is but following will generate your above query-

```
const sql = knex('resources')
   .leftJoin((query) => {
      query
         .columns([
            'resource_id',
            knex.raw('sum(price) as PostScoreSum')
         ])
         .from('prices')
         .where('dateto', '>', '2019-06-8')
         .where('datefrom', '<', '2019-06-8')
         .groupBy('resources_id')
         .as('BB')
   }, 'resources.resources_id', 'BB.resource_id')
   .toSQL();
console.log(sql) ;
```

Comment: Great. I didn't know how to write selection (query) => {...}), which will act as table into join.